# how can i add values to hashTable using Codedom in C#

Tags: c#

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement hashTableParam = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement();
            hashTableParam.Name = "hashtable";
            hashTableParam.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));
```

In the above code i tried to do a basic declaration for hashTable.
Now i need to added values to the hash table(key,value).

```
ht.Add("testKey","testData")
```

i.e how can i generate such code to add keys and values to HashTable programatically using codeDom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a way to do this that is more CodeDom oriented, which would allow for easier cross language support, but this will work

Assuming you already have a class created and a method, create a new CodeSnippetExpression and put the code you want in it, and then add that to your method body.

Comment: Why the downvotE? this exactly answers the user's question?